# How to get only number from .address VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string, numbers, userform

I'm trying to code a userform in which if a cmdbuton is pressed the userform will evaluate in which of the two textboxes the data is and look at the position (first textobx) or find the name of the data (second textbox).

I'm having problems to analyze the name of the textbox. I would like to find the name, get its location and load in another userform all the data from that row. The problem is I don't know how to take away the number from the .address that I get when I find the word.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
If Not TextBox1.value = "" And TextBox2.value = "" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 15) = TextBox1.value
    Unload Me 
    OpisVentila.Show
ElseIf TextBox1.value = "" And Not TextBox2.value = "" Then
Dim y As Range
Dim x As String
Dim z As String
Dim s As String
    x = TextBox2.Text
    Set y = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(x)
    z = y.Address(0, 0)
    s = StrConv(z, vbUnicode)
    s = Split(Left(s, Len(s) - 1, vbNullChar))
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 15) = s
    Unload Me 
    PromjenaVentila.Show
ElseIf Not TextBox1.value = "" And Not TextBox2.value = "" Then
    Msgbox "Please enter one way to find the desired location"
    TextBox1 = ""
    TextBox2 = ""
Else
    Msgbox "You didn't chose any way to find the desired location"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So from A4 you want A? Try `z = y.Address(1,1)` and `split(z, "$")(1)`. If you want the number use `(2)` instead. And check that `y` finds something first.

Comment: In textbox1 they write "5" for example if their data is in the 5th row? and if they dont know the row, but know that their data is called "Puma" then they should type that in textbox2? if you then just wanna find the row that has puma in it, use `GoodVariableName = application.match(textbox2.value, sheet(1).Range("A:A"), 0)` consider using an error catcher (`application.iferror` works great). Or you could just do `Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(x).row" without set to have y be the needed row in column A?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will give you the row number:

```
Dim y as Range
Dim z As Integer
Set y = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(x)
z = y.Row
```